# Sorting a dictionary by values if it occurs once otherwise by keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have this dictionary and I need to sort the words by value. But when two or more words have the same value, I need to sort those words by alphabet but I don't know how to do that. Can u help me?

```
dict = {'BLACK': 0, 'brown': 1, 'RED': 2, 'orange': 4, 'YELLOW': 7, 'green': 5, 'BLUE': 4,
        'violet': 2, 'GRAY': 3, 'White': 6}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), you can construct an ordered mapping which still has the benefits of a dictionary, such as O(1) lookup.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'BLACK': 0, 'brown': 1, 'RED': 2, 'orange': 4, 'YELLOW': 7,
     'green': 5, 'BLUE': 4, 'violet': 2, 'GRAY': 3, 'White': 6}

od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0].casefold())))

print(od)

OrderedDict([('BLACK', 0), ('brown', 1), ('RED', 2), ('violet', 2), ('GRAY', 3),
             ('BLUE', 4), ('orange', 4), ('green', 5), ('White', 6), ('YELLOW', 7)])
```

Since you are using both key and value for ordering, it's good practice to sort using tuples from `dict.items`. In addition, use `str.casefold` for case-insensitive ordering.

Finally, never shadow built-ins such as `dict`. Use `dict_` or `d` instead for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the fact that `tuple` compares its lements one-by-one.

```
d = {'BLACK': 0, 'brown': 1, 'RED': 2, 'orange': 4, 'YELLOW': 7, 'green': 5, 'BLUE': 4,
     'violet': 2, 'GRAY': 3, 'White': 6}
result = sorted(d, key=lambda k: (d[k], k.lower()))
```

Also fixed that `dict` shouldn't be used as a variable name - it's a built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted`:

```
>>> d = {'BLACK': 0, 'brown': 1, 'RED': 2, 'orange': 4, 'YELLOW': 7, 'green': 5, 'BLUE': 4,
        'violet': 2, 'GRAY': 3, 'White': 6}
>> sorted(d, key=lambda i: (d[i], i.lower()))
['BLACK', 'brown', 'RED', 'violet', 'GRAY', 'BLUE', 'orange', 'green', 'White', 'YELLOW']
```

Note: this assumes that everything should be lowercase, as python sorts uppercase words before lowercase words.

Also I renamed your variable to `d` because `dict` is a builtin.

To breakdown what’s happening:

`sorted` on a dictionary returns the keys sorted by a function `key` supplied (default is direct comparison of the keys)

```
>>> sorted(d)
['BLACK', 'BLUE', 'GRAY', 'RED', 'White', 'YELLOW', 'brown', 'green', 'orange', 'violet']
```

To sort by value, use `dict.get`:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get)
['BLACK', 'brown', 'RED', 'violet', 'GRAY', 'orange', 'BLUE', 'green', 'White', 'YELLOW']
```

Then we have to sort by the key in case of a tie. Because python compares its tuples one-by-one, we can construct a tuple of `(value, key)` and it will compare the items, then if they’re the same it will compare the items.

```
>>> (4, "blue") < (4, "orange")
True
>>> (4, "blue") < (3, "orange")
False
```

Comment: looks like the result is wrong, 4 shouldn't appear before 1 if I didn't misread

Comment: Oh whoops I sorted it backwards

Comment: @rassar You only need to sort the words that have the same value by alphabet

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> d = {'BLUE': 4, 'brown': 1, 'BLACK': 0, 'YELLOW': 7, 'violet': 2, 'orange': 4, 'green': 5, 'White': 6, 'GRAY': 3, 'RED': 2}
>>> t = (zip(d.values(), d.keys()))
>>> sorted(t)
[(0, 'BLACK'), (1, 'brown'), (2, 'RED'), (2, 'violet'), (3, 'GRAY'), (4, 'BLUE'), (4, 'orange'), (5, 'green'), (6, 'White'), (7, 'YELLOW')]
```

Comment: I need to return it as a sorted dictionary with the words as keys en their correspondent value as value